# Shapes library similar to PowerPoint

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, shapes

I really like how 2D Shapes work in MS PowerPoint. I was wondering if there any library for C# .NET that would allow me to use same functionality with easy in my application. 
I am looking for adding 2D shapes, re-sizing, moving, snapping two shapes to each other, group re-sizing, rotating, showing help lines when you snap two shapes together.

I tried to google and search here on stackexchange but came across few libraries that require a lot of manual work to get simple things working.

So my questions is: Is there any .NET library to be able include shapes functionality into my application with limited effort and short time.

Please share your experience if you have used any of the libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: That said, you're looking for WPF, winforms doesn't support any of that.

Comment: _"winforms doesn't support any of that"_ - not true, it just wouldn't fall into line with the _"limited effort and short time"_ requirement.

Comment: ok, so far I used Graphics to draw lines and squares, but I need to do complex computation to get two shapes to snap to each other. Can you provide example in WPF how can I create two parallelograms and snap them one to another by dragging, similar to what you can do in PowerPoint.